# Azure InstanceInput endpoint usage

Tags: azure

Can someone please post a sample code for using InstanceInput endpoints?
I used the below configuration in a worker role where a sample WCF service listens at port 8080.

```xml
<Endpoints>
  <InstanceInputEndpoint name="InstanceAccess" protocol="tcp" localPort="8080">
    <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
      <FixedPortRange max="10105" min="10101" />
    </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
  </InstanceInputEndpoint>
</Endpoints>
```

But I was not able to access this WCF service from an external consumer using any of the ports 10101 to 10105. Should we use the public DNS name of the Azure service along with the public ports in the give range?

Also, I was not able to access this endpoint details from within the worker role OnStart() method. I used RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["InstanceAccess"]. But it does not return a RoleInstanceEndpoint. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think the Azure Cmopute Emulator currently doesn't support InstanceInputEndpoint, so you can't really test it local. If I deploy an application on Azure everything seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://sdrv.ms/MTIzL2) is a sample Visual Studio solution which uses Azure InstanceInput endpoint and hosts a WCF service on a worker role. The WCF service running on each of the individual instances can be accessed using the Azure DNS name and the public port mapped to that instance. I used the following endpoint configuration.

```xml
  <Endpoints>
      <InstanceInputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="tcp" localPort="10100">
        <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
          <FixedPortRange max="10110" min="10106" />
        </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
      </InstanceInputEndpoint>
    </Endpoints>
```

This endpoint was somehow not accessible from within the WorkerRole (both OnStart() and Run() methods). So I used 'localhost'.

```cs
  string endpointIP = "localhost:10100";

  if (RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints.Keys.Contains("Endpoint1"))
  {
      IPEndPoint externalEndPoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint1"].IPEndpoint;
      endpointIP = externalEndPoint.ToString();
  }
```

The solution also contains a console client which uses the hosted DNS name to invoke these individual WCF services.

Comment: When attempting to test the linked solution in the compute emulator, the worker role's instances after the first hit AddressAlreadyInUseException. I guess that's to be expected if the emulator is just binding onto the hosting machine's available ports...

Answer (score 0):

InstanceInput endpoint is not working locally but once deployed it is working fine and assigned a different port for each instance, based on the port range it is allowed to create an instance, you cannot create instance more than the specified port range in the configuration. for example, port range is 101 - 105 you can create only 5 instance