# Getting Azure InstanceInput endpoint port

Tags: azure

I'm want my client to communicate with a specific WorkerRole instance, so I'm trying to use  InstanceInput endpoints.

My project is based on the example provided in this question: [Azure InstanceInput endpoint usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201660/azure-instanceinput-endpoint-usage)

The problem is that I don't get the external IP address + port for the actual instance, when using `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint1"].IPEndpoint;` 
I just get internal address with the local port (e.g. 10.x.x.x:10100). I know that I can get the public IP address via DNS lookup (xxx.cloudapp.net), but I don't have a glue how to get the correct public port for each instance.

One possible solution would be: get the instance number (from `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id`) and add this instance number to the `FixedPortRange` minimum (e.g. 10106). This would imply that the first instance will **always** have the port 10106, the second instance **always** 10107 and so on. This solution seems a bit hacky to me, since I don't know how Windows Azure assigns the instances to the ports.

Is there a better (correct) way to retrieve the public port for each instance?

Question #2:
Are there any information about the Azure Compute Emulator supporting InstanceInput endpoints? (As I already mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201660/azure-instanceinput-endpoint-usage#comment17559730_11201660): It seems that the Azure Compute Emulator currently doesn't support InstanceInputEndpoint).

**Second solution (much better)**:

To get the public port, the porperty `PublicIPEndpoint` can be used (I don't know why I didn't notice this property in the first place).

*Usage*: `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint1"].PublicIPEndpoint;`

*Warning*:
The IP address in the property is unused (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstanceendpoint.publicipendpoint.aspx).

**First solution**:

As 'artfulmethod' already mentioned, the REST operation `Get Deployment` retrieves interesting information about the current deployment. Since I encountered some small annoying 'issues', I'll will provide the code for the REST client here (in case someone else is having a similiar problem):

```
X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

string footPrint = "xxx"; // enter the footprint of the certificate you use to upload the deployment (aka Management Certificate)
X509Certificate2Collection certs = 
certificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, footPrint, false); 
if (certs.Count != 1) {
    // client certificate cannot be found - check footprint
}
string url = "https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<service-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>"; // replace <xxx> with actual values
try {
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.ClientCertificates.Add(certs[0]);
  request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01"); // very important, otherwise you get an HTTP 400 error, specifies in which version the response is formatted
  request.Method = "GET";

  var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // get response

  string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd() // get response body
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // handle error
}
```

The string 'result' contains all the information about the deployment (format of the XML is described in section 'Response Body' @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx)

Comment: FYI - documentation for `PublicIPEndpoint` says: *The value of this property is null when running in the emulator.*
http://207.46.22.237/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstanceendpoint.publicipendpoint.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information about your deployments, including the VIPs and public ports for your role instances, use the [Get Deployment operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx) on the Service Management API. The response body includes an [InstanceInputList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx#InputEndpointList).

Comment: Thx, that should to the trick. I'll post my solution in the question.